# Allow user to send email to many different dynamic addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I am running a Ruby on Rails 3.2 application where users can, among other things, send emails to their clients that are represented in various ways in the database.

Depending on what selection a user makes, this can be a dynamic list of 50-200 email addresses. The list can be different from day to day depending on numerous factors. Setting up a fixed mailing list at the email provider is not an option.

What would be the best way to expose this functionality to my users?

Currently, I am running a paid SMTP server behind the application that handles all the email, but I've been having SPAM flagging problems when I try to send a single email through them with 50-200 BCC's.

I have also tried to give users the option to send email through their own email clients via a mailto: link. However, depending on browser, Windows version and email client used, a mailto: link does not work whenever it exceeds a certain amount of characters or addresses.

What would be a best practice to solve this problem and offer this functionality to my clients?

Comment: You can try mandrill api's for bulk emailing

Answer (score 0):

Stuffing your BCC field with e-mails is a surefire way of getting flagged as spam. Googling "[BCC spam](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=bcc%20spam&oq=bcc%20spam&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1079j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)" will highlight this problem:

> It is better to send an individual message to each recipient, rather than using multiple addresses in the BCC field because many spam filters (and many ISP's) automatically flag multiple recipients as spam.

Instead, loop through the selected recipients, and send one e-mail per, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072939/send-email-to-all-users-in-rails).

```
def calling_method
  @recipients.each do |recipient|
    send_email(recipient.email, recipient.name)
  end
end

def send_email(recipient_email, recipient_name)
  mail(to: recipient_email, subject: recipient_name)
end
```