# Send email to all users from rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have added rails_admin in my application. Now I need to add an additional feature, that is send email to all users from the rails application. How can I add a new view with in rails_admin. Currently I have added a new static menu in rails_admin.rb

```
config.navigation_static_links = {
'Compose' => '/admin/email'
}
```

But it is opened in a new tab as a seperate view with no side bar, footer, header etc..
I want to add this feature like dashboard. Please give some useful hints for my issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

probably you will need to create what `RailsAdmin` define as [`Action`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643500/hitham-s-alqadheeb) for your `Admin` role and make sure you manage correctly the `admin` authentication with `Devise`

You can implement a method that sends email with `ActionMailer`, I am quoting the solution from [Hitham S.AlQadheeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643500/hitham-s-alqadheeb) from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072939/send-email-to-all-users-in-rails#20073035). [Go check his post for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072939/send-email-to-all-users-in-rails#20073035)

> For each call to the mailer method one email is sent in scheduled worker

```
def calling_method
   @users.each do |user|
     send_digest(user.email, user.name)
   end
end
```

> in user mailer

```
def send_digest(user_email, user_name)
   mail(to: user_email, subject: user_name)
end
```

Comment: Currently, I have added route and in admin_controller a method is defined to do the send mail to the users using ActionMailer. The mail is a generalized feature for admin login, not a model action. So need to show link in the title tab.

Comment: Also I have created view in which admin can provide the subject and content for the mail. But it is opened in a new tab. I want to show it in the same tab with rails admin side bar, header etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom action
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action
Based on the dashboard 
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb

And if you want a link to it visible at all times, you will need to override the existing navigation partial on your project.
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/_navigation.html.haml

Comment: If we add a new action for a model in rails_admin. To apply the change do we have to restart the production server ? I have added a custom action in lib folder and included in rails_admin.rb config file

Comment: Yes, you have to restart the development and production servers.